# Understanding realloc() in C

Tags: c, realloc

In this example from: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/
why are there two pointers: numbers and more_numbers? Can I use:

```
numbers = (int*) realloc (numbers, count * sizeof(int));
if (numbers!=NULL) {
       numbers[count-1]=input;
}
else {
       free (numbers);
       puts ("Error (re)allocating memory");
       exit (1);
}
```

Comment: `free (numbers);` : Nonsense.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Not exactly nonsense, but a no-op, since this is effectively `free( NULL )`. *Another* bug on cplusplus.com -- which is why you shouldn't use that page. It *crawls* with stuff like this.

Comment: Why do sites like this insist on promoting bad practice?  Do not use `puts` to print an error message.  Error messages belong on stderr.  Use `perror` or `fprintf` and `strerror`. (Do not use `fputs` either, since you are probably discarding the system error message if you do.)

Comment: @DevSolar, the code on that website is correct in this instance (albeit having some questionable coding style), OP is asking what's wrong with his self-authored alternative version

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Agreed, it's a sidetracked discussion. But I've come across so much questionable content on cplusplus.com, including the fact that they don't seem interested in ever fixing anything, that its use should be discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see why your version is wrong, you need to realise what realloc does. It does one of two things: If there is enough memory, it will return a new pointer and the old one becomes invalid. If there isn't enough memory, it will return NULL and the old pointer stays valid and unchanged.

You *must* store the result of realloc into a temporary variable, and not overwrite the old pointer. The reason is that if realloc returns NULL, and you overwrote the old pointer with NULL, you lost access to your existing data. So the correct way is:

```
int* tmp = (int*) realloc (numbers, count * sizeof(int));
if (tmp!=NULL) {
    // realloc was successful. The old value of numbers is now rubbish. 
    // Store the result of realloc into numbers and continue. 
    numbers = tmp; 
    numbers[count-1]=input;
}
else {
    // realloc failed. The old value of numbers is unchanged but doesn't have enough
    // space to store input. You need to handle the error somehow. 
    free (numbers);
    puts ("Error (re)allocating memory");
    exit (1);
}
```

If you had stored the realloc () result directly into numbers, the "else" branch wouldn't know the old value of numbers anymore and couldn't free that memory.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that example appears a little extended is to adequately deal with a failure to realloc.

```
numbers = (int*) realloc (numbers, count * sizeof(int));
if (numbers!=NULL) {
       numbers[count-1]=input;
}
else {
       free (numbers);
```

This will *not* work in the error condition; you'll be trying to free a value which you just confirmed is NULL, which probably isn't what you intend. Additionally, you've lost the (still valid) original pointer in this case (the purpose of the more_numbers pointer in your example), losing access to the data you have there and losing the ability to release the buffer.

Comment: yep, one should definitely not use the old Ptr DIRECTLY, or a failure causes a memory leak

Comment: @Danvil it's not an error but it's also not of any value -- it's one thing to do it when you're not bothering to check for NULL, but it's downright useless to do it in a conditional that already knows it's NULL -- which is why I stated "isn't what you intended" and not something stronger.

Comment: I also include reasons for why it will not work. If you want to argue the reasons then do so, I've given them to you for that purpose. That one will exit later is truly not a good reason to espouse poor memory management patterns now; patterns in use now will get used later when the conditions have changed but establishing valid patterns now guards against that.

Comment: There is a difference between bad style and an actual segmentation fault. But I totally agree with you that the call to `free` does not make any sense here.

Comment: could you explain bit more why `numbers = (int*) realloc (numbers, count * sizeof(int));` is wrong?

Comment: @zud on the (typical) premise that `numbers` points to a valid buffer before the call, and in the code path that `realloc() fails (because it can't find enough memory to enlarge the buffer), `realloc()` will return NULL. In this case `numbers` is now NULL but its previous buffer is still allocated and contains the data it held before -- but the program just lost the pointer to it. Without the pointer the program can no longer access its data, and it can not return the buffer to the system.

Answer (score 1):

According to link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/

it is written *"The program prompts the user for numbers until a zero character is entered. Each time a new value is introduced the memory block pointed by numbers is increased by the size of an int."*

have a look at the function realloc() in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm

void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);

The function returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory, or NULL if the request fails.

**ptr --** This is the pointer to a memory block previously allocated with malloc, calloc or realloc to be reallocated.If this is NULL, a new block is allocated and a pointer to it is returned by the function

**size --** This is the new size for the memory block, in bytes.If it is 0 and ptr points to an existing block of memory, the memory block pointed by ptr is de-allocated and a NULL pointer is returned

So after allocating memory this function returns a void pointer and it is type-casted to an integer pointer to use in the code. So each time a code is entered the memory allocated will be incremented 1 times by the sizeof(int) and the value is stored in that area.

**more_numbers** is the pointer which points to the starting address of the location of the memory allocated by the realloc()

**numbers** is the pointer which points to the array where the inputs are stored

In case if the memory allocation fails the entire memory is de-allocated using free();

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function (hope i did this right):

```
/// int*-argument passed by-pointer
bool Enlarge(int** input, size_t new_count, int new_val)
{
    void* numbers = NULL;  // local ptr

    numbers = (int*) realloc (*input, new_count*sizeof(int));
    if (numbers!=NULL) {

      *input = (int*)numbers;
      (*input)[new_count - 1] = new_val;

      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Use it:

```
int* old = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
if (!old)
    return -1;
old[0] = 11; old[1] = 22;
if (!Enlarge(&old,3,33))
{
    free(old);
    return -2;
}
printf("A: %d, B: %d, C: %d\n", old[0], old[1], old[2]);
if (old) {  free(old);  }
```

Just beware to pass the ptr as `int**` and not as `int*` (e.g. when specifying &old[0] instead of &old.